# How to communicate between process in real time?

Tags: python

I have two processes and the data of one process has to be communicated to the other. I wrote a basic queue in order to communicate in real time but it doesn't serve the purpose.

The following is example code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process , Pipe , Queue
a , b = Pipe()
q = Queue()

def f(name):
i = 0
while i < 4:
    q.put(i)
    i += 1


def t():
 print q.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
 p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
 p.start()
 p.join()
 p1 = Process(target=t, args= (''))
 p1.start()
 p1.join()
```

The expected output was  `0 1 2 3 4`, but I only get `0`. 
How can I resolve this?

Comment: I should also mention that your code indentation is very awkward, and I see from your post source that you're using tabs and spaces in an inconsistent way. I would recommend using only spaces (or only tabs); most decent text editors have a setting that converts tabs to spaces.

Comment: well sorry for that , i use geany and its kinda messy when it comes to indentation. soon will be switching to some other editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this version :

```
def t():
    while True:
        try:
            print q.get(timeout=1)
        except:
            break
```

Comment: Don't catch all exceptions, you'll hide bugs that way.

Answer (score 1):

You're only calling get() once. It returns one item at a time.

(As an aside, your function f is very non-Pythonic, ty:

```
def f(name):
    for i in range(4):
        q.put(i)
```

You're also using q as a global...

Comment: works well . only one problem , i dont know how many times the data is inserted in the queue , is there any way to pop out until its empty. i did try Cedric`s method , but it also throws some exception.

Comment: Hard to know when the queue is "empty" because it may get filled at a later time by the other process, but since you're doing all the filling, then joining the writer process, `while not q.empty(): q.get()` (appropriate newline/indent, of course)